# Changing status bar color on Android devices with AngularJS

Tags: android, angularjs, mobile-website, material-design

Some mobile websites change the color of the status bar and search bar in Android devices. For example when I open the BBC mobile website on my Android 5.0 device, top bar changes to red color.

Anybody have any idea how this can be achieved using AngularJS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The HTML solution for this is a simple `meta` tag (with your customized color) added to the `head` section of your html template:

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#0041C8">
```

Note that this will currently only have an effect for users running Chrome on Android 5.0+ with the "Merge tabs and apps" setting on.

---

If you want the color to be dynamic, you can bind it to a value in an Angular controller. When the value changes, the displayed color will change as well. There are several different ways to accomplish this (and this is a non-exhaustive list).

#### Option 1. `head`-scoped controller

In this method, we create a controller that is bound to the template's `head`. Because `head` doesn't have any UI components, we can't change the color value directly on the scope from user actions. (We *can* accomplish this indirectly by listening for events from other controllers or injecting a shared service.) However, this method is still useful for setting a calculated color on load. For example, we could change the color based on the time of day.

First, create a controller for the head:

```
.controller('HeadCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.theme.color = calculateColor();

    function calculateColor() {
        var hour = (new Date()).getHours();
        var lightness = Math.sin(hour / 24 * Math.PI) * 100;
        return 'hsl(200, 25%, ' + lightness + '%)';
    }
})
```

Then add the binding to your template:

```
<head ng-controller="HeadCtrl">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="{{ theme.color }}">
</head>
```

#### Option 2. `head`-scoped controller with service

As mentioned above, there are ways of binding user actions from other controllers to the color value on our `HeadCtrl`. This method uses a service to make the color configurable by other controllers.

First, create the service with the initial color value:

```
.service('theme', function () {
    this.color = '#0041C8';
})
```

Then create a controller for the head, inject the `theme` service, and add it to the scope:

```
.controller('HeadCtrl', function ($scope, theme) {
    $scope.theme = theme;
})
```

The template binding is the same as in Option 1:

```
<head ng-controller="HeadCtrl">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="{{ theme.color }}">
</head>
```

You can now inject the service into other controllers. Any changes to `theme.color` in these controllers will be reflected in the `meta` tag.

#### Option 3. `html`-scoped controller

This method uses the prototypical inheritance of nested controllers to make the theme color available for other controllers to change.

First, create the controller with the initial color value:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.theme = {
        color: '#0041C8'
    };
})
```

Notice that `theme` is an object rather than a single `themeColor` string value. This is important for controller inheritance.

Then add the binding to your template:

```
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <head>
        <meta name="theme-color" content="{{ theme.color }}">
    </head>
```

Your other controllers will now inherit `theme` on their `$scope`, so you can change `$scope.theme.color` in the controller or `theme.color` in the template. For example, this creates a button that changes the color to red when clicked:

```
<div ng-controller="SomeOtherCtrl">
    <!-- ... -->
    <button ng-click="theme.color = '#FF0000'">Red</button>
</div>
```

---

This answer ended up being more of a lesson in sharing data between controllers, but it illustrates that you can bind color data to the `content` attribute and the client will update the displayed color.

Source: [HTML5 Rocks](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2014/11/Support-for-theme-color-in-Chrome-39-for-Android)

Comment: You earn my upvote if you can make this a truly Angular relevant answer - would `content="{{themeColor}}"` being changed via databinding be reflected in the view? In other words (Angular or not), can you continue to modify that tag and and the device continue to respond to changes?

Comment: @m59 Honestly, I thought the Angular part was irrelevant so I didn't even think about it in that context. Thanks for opening my eyes! I've updated my answer with dynamic Angular solutions.